# How to register jsPDF-AutoTable plugin with jsPDF in webpack?

Tags: webpack, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I've created a vendor module according to [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) and set *jsPDF* as a dependency. How do I achieve, that **jsPDF-AutoTable** plugin will be registered with *jsPDF* before injecting *jsPDF* into my vendor module?

I've already solved `jsPDF is not defined` using *ProvidePlugin* in my *webpack.config.js* file like this:

```
config.plugins = [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jsPDF: 'jspdf'
    })
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [example](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/tree/master/examples/webpack) how to use webpack in the jspdf autotable repository. Basically you simply need to require the plugin after jspdf.

```
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');
require('jspdf-autotable');
```

You shouldn't need to use the provider plugin with the latest version of jspdf.

Comment: Latest versions of `jspdf-autotable` is for webpack 2, so I have to use `ProvidePlugin`. My webpack has vendor script, where I mention all included 3rd party plugins, like `jsPDF` and `jsPDF-AutoTable`. The Problem is, even if I apply your code snippet, autotable got injected into locally defined variable *jsPDF* and when I hit the breakpoint my vendor plugin, where I require `jsPDF` as a dependency, it hasn't `AutoTable` as a registered plugin. Maybe, it's how webpack works, but no workaround comes to my mind, to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Use below combination of import this will work fine with webpack too

import jsPDF from "jspdf";

require("jspdf-autotable");